# What is the right way to scale a Flex application up to fullscreen?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, fullscreen

Fullscreen mode and I have been battling for a while in this Flex application, and I'm coming up short on Google results to end my woes.  I have no problem going into fullscreen mode by doing a `Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`, but the rest of the content just sits there in the top, left corner at it's original size.

All right, says I, I'll just do a `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL` and make *it* figure out how to pull this off.  And it looks like it does.  Except that when you mouse over the individual checkboxes and buttons and various components, they all *fidget* slightly.  Just a slight jump up or down as they resize...*on mouse over*.  Well, this is frustrating, but bearable.  I can always just invoke `invalidateSize()` explicitly for all of them.

But for the comboboxes.  The ones at the bottom have their menus go off the bottom of the screen, and when I pop out of fullscreen mode, their drop downs cut off half way.  I have no idea how to fix *that*.  Can someone step in here, and put me out of my misery?

What is the right way to scale a Flex application up to fullscreen?

```
var button:Button = button_fullscreen;
try {
    if(stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN) {
        Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
        button.label = "View Fullscreen Mode";
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    } else {
        Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        button.label = "Exit Fullscreen Mode";
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
    }
    invalidateSizes(); // Calls invalidateSize() explicitly on several components.
} catch(error:SecurityError) {
    Alert.show("The security settings of your computer prevent this from being displayed in fullscreen.","Error: "+error.name+" #"+error.errorID);
} catch(error:Error) {
    Alert.show(error.message,error.name+" #"+error.errorID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes things go wrong with flex :)

try the following approach

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

then on resize or added to stage set the scaling manually

```
private function updateScaling():void
{
   if(stage.stageWidth != width || stage.stageHeight != height)
   {
       var scaling:Number = 1;
       if(width>height)
       {
          scaling = stage.stageWidth / width;
       }
       else
       {
         scaling = stage.stageHeight / height;
       }

       scaleX = scaleY = scaling;
   }
}
```